# Horizontal Table Spillover CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have table with only two, long-ish columns. I want the display the table in a way that creates "meta"-columns from the regular columns. In other words, if the table is more than five rows long, I want the next five rows to be displayed next to the right of the first rows and so on.

I've been searching around but since I'm new to CSS, I'm not exactly sure of the terminology. I'm sure people have had to deal with this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#css-columns

```
-webkit-column-count: 2; /* Set to number of columns */
-webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #bbb;
-webkit-column-gap: 2em;
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: These properties are only supported by Opera and -webkit- browsers (Safari and Chrome).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work for Chrome. I'm not sure how I would do it with IE or Firefox, though.

Comment: One thing I'm finding weird though is to show the extra columns, I have to highlight them or scroll so their off the browser window. I'm not sure why they don't show up automatically. I'm using Chromium.